# python: отследить вызов функций по имени

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, стек

подскажите, как в питоне можно зная имя функции понять сколько раз ее вызвали

т.е. есть некоторый, недоступный для пользователя код (обёрнутый в вызов функции) внутри которого вызывается функция с именем `func_name`

по идее (как я понимаю), надо получить доступ к стеку вызовов функций и просто подсчитать сколько раз встречается нужный мне вызов, т.е. что-то такое (в псевдокоде):

```
stack_start()

func()

arr = stack_stop()

count = len(i for i in arr if i == func_name
```

но как это реализовать на практике?

как понимаю надо смотреть в сторону библиотеки `inspect`?

Comment: Посмотрите этот тред: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717396/10090254

Comment: @floydya, к сожалению там всё про то, как подсчитать вызовы ИЗВЕСТНОЙ функции, а мне надо как раз подсчитать вызовы неизвестной функции, ну или другими словами сторонней функции, не моей, так что я не могу в нее вставлять код или ее чем-то оборачивать

Comment: Монки патчинг в питоне изишно делается

Answer (score 1):

через `settrace` все можно сделать

```
from sys import settrace

def tracer(frame, event, arg=None):
    if event == "call":
        # тут делаем что хотим с функциями frame.f_code.co_name

    return tracer

settrace(tracer)
```